# cannot insert 21,000 records in my table. The browser keeps freezing

Tags: php, mysql

i am able to insert only 1500 records into my table in mysql, but when I try to insert around 21,000 records, the browser freezes. what can be the problem? Also, i have noticed that everytime i run the program, i get a little more data inserted. For instance the fisrt time I run the program, i will have 1500 records, i delete the table et run the program again, and that time i will have 1550, then, 2500. Why is that? Any suggestions? The code is in php5 and my database in MySQL.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have shell access to the server?

Comment: I am using a WampServer.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have shell access and cannot adjust the php.ini to enlarge the max_execution_time and max_input_time configuration variables, your best answer is to split the large file into smaller chunks and try loading them one at a time.

Otherwise, find and set the following in your php.ini:

```
max_execution_time 600
max_input_time 600
memory_limit 256M
```

You can also check the apache/php error log to see what is specifically happening when the process crashes.

Finally, you can try importing it directly into mysql from the commandline:

```
mysql -uroot -p databasename < file.sql
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the command prompt, login to MySql, and import the dump file:

```
 mysql -u username -p database_name < dumpfile.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing 21,000 records as a single transaction to an ISAM table?  More records means a larger rollback segment has to be maintained.  Could that be the explanation for your problem?  If yes, smaller units of work might be a good idea.  Your 21,000 records would mean 14 separate units of work if the batch size is 1,500.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, everytime I run the program, i notice more data are inserted. The last time i run the program, i had 5291 records inserted. Those records are extracted from xml files.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are doing a script to insert 21k rows, you can use a CLI script, and set the max_execution_time in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini (depend the OS).

Other solution is generate a file with all inserts queryes, and execute the file by console:

```
 mysql -hserver -uyouruser -pyourpassword DBName < generated_file.sql
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's been only two months that i am coding in php. i am still learning. maybe if i post the code, i will know better where to make changes. This is the code I wrote: